# Birthday line to get tickets in a unique setup

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

There is a long line of people waiting outside a theatre to buy tickets. The theatre owner comes out and announces that the first person to have a birthday same as someone standing anywhere before him in the line gets a free ticket. Where will you stand to maximize your chance?